# How to create Curved Tabbar Flutter widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Could please assist me to create this curved & colored tabBar widget same like the picture below.
[image]

Comment: You can try with Stack and animatedPosition.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `TabBar` with `Container` widget.

```
Container(
  decoration:BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
    topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
    topRight: Radius.circular(30),
  ),
 child:TabBar(tabs:[ //your tabbar children here ])
```